# managing multiple values in android

Tags: android

I am doing project on ecommerce app.
In my dashboard activity I am getting username value from login activity and mobile number from main activity. 
I want to check those two values and set in text view according to incoming values.
How can I achieve?

Comment: I am using json parser and phpmysql

Answer (score 0):

You could either store them in a [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) or similar, or you could store them in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

You can look into some more options [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences Like example store value and get value entire application

```
//Store value
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit(); 
editor.putString(Name, n);
editor.putString(Phone, ph);
editor.commit();

//getvalue
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString(Name, null);
```

**i hope help this**